# How can a process eat more/less virtual memory (according to top) then the page size makes available?

Tags: memory, virtual-memory

The operating system runs on physical memory and provides an individual, virtual address space to each process, for storing data. To make the transfer between virtual and physical memory easier.
The operating system divides the part of the memory, it doesn't need for its own purpose, into pages. So the virtual address space, a process interacts with, is a multiple of these pages.

Why isn't this true? Why isn't the actual memory consumption (as shown on my `top`) a multiple,

```
PID    VIRT     TIME+  COMMAND
  986  212076  11:22.29 Xorg
 1194  504916   1:56.15 pulseaudio
 1252  445884   0:13.69 xfce4-terminal
  827    4256   0:08.16 acpid
```

of the pagesize, my operating system uses?

`acpid` uses 4256 bytes of Virtual memory. `getconf PAGESIZE` shows that my system uses a page size of 4096 bytes (4KiB)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It actually behaves exactly like you describe.

Top's memory output is in `KiB` which is why every entry is divisable by 4, since your page size is 4KiB.

Comment: ._.  .... Well, I am officially a retard. kinda new to this site, should I delete this nonsense or keep the question up?

Comment: Leave it up.  I've seen **much** worse.